# Action to stow an item

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What kind of action is it to stow an item in pathfinder? There's plenty of discussion on what kind of action it is to draw an item, but not the reverse.

In particular, I don't care about weapons and shields. I care about things like potions and spellbooks and placing them in traditional backpacks.

For some reason, I remember this costing a standard action, but I haven't been able to find anything to back this up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Pathfinder SRD has this to say on the matter:

> Moving or manipulating an item is usually a move action.
>
> This includes **retrieving or putting away a stored item**, picking up
>   an item, moving a heavy object, and opening a door.

Emphasis mine.

There is no special meaning to the term "stored item", rather, it is an editing error. They tried to condense their wording and ended up with a nonsensical statement of putting away stored items, which is by definition impossible. It *should* read "This includes retrieving a stored item, putting away an item, picking up an item, moving a heavy object, and opening a door." The editing error [originated](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#manipulateanItem) in 3.5, and Paizo has yet to fix the nonfunctional wording.